# Two multi-file LaTeX projects sharing files

Tags: input

I'm new here so I'll probably ask a naive question. Please let me know if an dhow I can improve my question.

I have written a long Latex document and I have split the chapters into different tex files, which are included in the final documents using \input{}.

Now I want to write an executive summary of the whole document, which should include only some sentences from each chapter. Is there a smart way to do that?

I'm naively thinking of "marking" somehow the sentences that I want in the executive summary and then automatically get the "marked" sentences.

As an example, you can have a look at the following:

Chapter1.tex

```
\marked{I want this sentence in the executive summary.}
I don't want this sentence in the executive summary.
```

Document.tex

```
\input{Chapter1.tex, onlyMarkedText=False}
```

ExecutiveSummary.tex

```
\input{Chapter1.tex, onlyMarkedText=True}
```

So that when I compile the Document I get

```
I want this sentence in the executive summary. 
I don't want this sentence in the executive summary.
```

and when compiling the ExecutiveSummary I get

```
I want this sentence in the executive summary.
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated!
Thanks,
Matteo

Comment: Several of the answers to [Managing multiple translation of a single document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60781/106162) can be adapted to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With packages `version` or `versions` you can define some emvironmemts that will or will not be typeset depending on a global variable.
This provides a solution to your problem. You could either toggle this variable in your main file according to the targeted document, or use another main specifically for the summary.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to reverse the markup in your `Chapter1.tex`:

```
I want this sentence in the executive summary.
\marked{I don't want this sentence in the executive summary.}
```

Then you just need to put `\long\def\marked#1{#1}\input{Chapter1.tex}` in your `Document.tex` and `\long\def\marked#1{}\input{Chapter1.tex}` in your other document. No extra packages needed.