# Generate a pdf for each language

Tags: pdf, babel, jobname

I have this document:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english, spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\section*{Hello, world!}
This is a document written in English.

\selectlanguage{spanish}
\section*{¡Hola, mundo!}
Este es un documento escrito en español.

\end{document}
```

And I execute this command to generate a PDF for Spanish:

```
pdflatex -jobname=manual-es "\AtBeginDocument{\selectlanguage{spanish}}" manual.tex
```

but I get the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-09-28>

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

<*> \AtBeginDocument{\selectlanguage{spanish}} m  
                                                anual.tex
? return
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
Missing character: There is no m in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no u in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no x in font nullfont!
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...cument{\selectlanguage{spanish}} manual.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on manual-es.log.
pdflatex: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.
```

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With this command no longer gives error but not generate only one language

pdflatex -jobname=.\out\manual-english "\AtBeginDocument{\selectlanguage{english}}\input{manual}"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the first argument is source rather than a filename, everything following it is also being treated as source.

You instead need to include `manual.tex` in a way that expands to its contents

```
pdflatex -jobname=manual-es "\AtBeginDocument{\selectlanguage{spanish}}\input{manual.tex}"
```

However, `\selectlanguage` just tells `babel` which language is currently being typeset, it doesn't help with selectively picking out some text to typeset.

In order to selectively typeset, we can follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60795) and use [`comment`](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english, spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}

\specialcomment{english}{\selectlanguage{english}}{}
\specialcomment{spanish}{\selectlanguage{spanish}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{english}
\section*{Hello, world!}
This is a document written in English.
\end{english}

\begin{spanish}
\section*{¡Hola, mundo!}
Este es un documento escrito en español.
\end{spanish}

\end{document}
```

Now everything within the `english` environments can be omitted with `\excludecomment{english}` and similar for `spanish`.
This can be achieved with

```
pdflatex -jobname=manual-es "\AtBeginDocument{\excludecomment{english}}\input{manual.tex}"
```

Or we can condition the compilation on `\jobname`, so no additional code needs to be passed at compile time, with either of:

1. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5231/106162) adding `\input \jobname` where in the same directory `manual-es.tex` contains `\excludecomment{english}` and `manual-en.tex` contains `\excludecomment{spanish}`.
2. [This TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-compjobnam), copying the `\StripPrefix` and `\jobis` definitions into `manual.tex`, and using

   ```
   \if\jobis{manual-es}
     \excludecomment{english}
   \fi
   \if\jobis{manual-en}
     \excludecomment{spanish}
   \fi
   ```

Then we only need to compile as

```
pdflatex -jobname=manual-es manual
```

The restrictive `\excludecomment{<other language>}`s can be replaced by putting `\excludecomment{<language>}` for all languages in `manual.tex` and then the `\excludecomment{<other language>}`s should be replaced by `\includecomment{<this language>}` in either `manual-en.tex` etc or inside the `\ifjobis{<language>}` depending what you use.  This would make compiling `manual.tex` "normally" show none of the language environments rather than all.

Comment: Thanks, Dai, your command works fine but the generated PDF document has all the content and not just Spanish.

Comment: @AlexSegura Ah, I'd assumed your tex file met your needs and the problem was how to compile it.

Comment: Hi Dai, yes, my first problem was the compilation, but the origin was to create a PDF document separated by the language specified in the command. Thanks for your comments :-D

Comment: @AlexSegura See my edit

Comment: Great Dai!! It works very well!! Thank you very much!!