# How to create a multi-lingual document capable to render into multi languages?

Tags: languages, parameters

I am thinking on some similar (intuitive tex code follows):

```
\en{That is the title}\de{Hier ist der Titel}
```

And then, if I somehow parametrize the rendering (for example, by giving some command line argument to the latex process) then it would be able to generate both the English and the German version of the same document.

Is it somehow possible?

I think, here we have actually not even a multi-lingual document but parametrized (preprocessed?) code, so actually also any similar solution is okay.

The sources I have found are mostly about using multiple languages in the same document. But not this is what I want to. I want to somehow "pre-process" the document to have the content on multiple languages, and generate always the one what I actually need to.

Comment: [Managing multiple translation of a single document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60781/106162), maybe also [Generate a pdf for each language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/675597/106162)