# How to do a small box synchronized translation?

Tags: minipage, hebrew, parallel

I would like to do something similar to the Artscroll Bibles, with a Hebrew text and a small box on the top with a synchronized translation.

In the following picture, the box in question is the upper left one, which contains another translation of the main interlinear text. Both text are verse numbered, so the problem is how to sync them. Using two parallel columns is not an option here. What I have in mind is more a synced minipage.

[image: like this]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Perhaps you will want to take a look at these answers, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16603/putting-two-texts-side-by-side and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50631/hebrew-vs-german-english-translation-side-by-side.

Comment: @Tonton, are you asking only about the inner-side-box (Onkalos translation), or also about the translation to English below each word? In the latter case, I'm not even sure your question has an RTL-specific element to it, and you might want to start with a simplified question about two runs of text in parallel.

Comment: About @MMA's comment: The first question is sort-of relevant, but I think in the bible case, you would have the text with markers either at the Pasuk (sentence) level or even at the word level. The example above starts and ends the translation box on exactly the same word, and the translation maintains the grammatical structure exactly. The second question does not seem relevant, since the layout there is sentence-by-sentence, with TeX only required to split lines across pages.

Comment: MMA The links you provided answer a different question. @einpoklum , yes I'm talking about the little box with the Targum. I know how to do the interlinear part or to synchronize translations in two columns, but not in a "box" whose dimension is different than the source text, as in the picture. Sorry for no being sufficiently clear !

Comment: We'll need to see something of what you've tried, otherwise this looks 'too broad' to me.

Comment: I’ve provided a different picture which I think illustrates the OP’s question better.